# [C++][SFML 2.2] Strange Performance Issues - Moving Mouse Lowers CPU Usage

Tags: c++, performance, sfml

I've been working on making a 2D Map Editor for the past two weeks or so, and I've just run into a very strange problem. As I was trying to optimize my code, for example, by making functions for what really should've been functions to begin with, I did something that made my CPU usage go through the roof. I've tried commenting out the different sections of code I thought were most likely the culprits (scrolling, rendering, other calculations) but to no avail. I think the issue might simply be trying to call things from within different functions, but for the sake of making this as modular as possible, I'd really like that functionality.

The other major change I've made since the file I'm comparing this to is I've ported all my variables into an external CPP file, since having the variables as global makes it a lot easier to use from within different functions. This is likely a very simple issue, but I can't for the life of me understand why it happens.

With the original code, I get around 2-3% CPU usage. With the new code, I get around 20-35%, BUT, if I move the mouse around, it'll drop to around 6-8%.

**tl;dr: After trying to optimize my code by using functions, I've somehow killed my performance, and found a strange quirk where moving the mouse greatly reduces CPU usage..**

```
//Most variables are declared in an external file
void editorLoop()
{
/***************************/
//See what user wants to do
/***************************/
std::cout << "Would you like to [O]pen a file, make [N]ew one, or [E]xit?\n";
std::cin >> openOrNewFile;
/************************/
//Create a new file
/***********************/
if (openOrNewFile == 'n' || openOrNewFile == 'N')
{
    createMap();
}
/***********************/
//Quit the program
/**********************/
else if (openOrNewFile == 'e' || openOrNewFile == 'E')
{
    return;
}
/************************/
//Open an existing file
/***********************/
else if (openOrNewFile == 'o' || openOrNewFile == 'O')
{
    openMap();
}
/**********************/
//Invalid input
/*********************/
else
{
    std::cout << "Please enter a valid input!\n";
    main();
}


/***********************/
//Create the Window
/***********************/
sf::RenderWindow gameWindow(sf::VideoMode(screenSizeX, screenSizeY, mapTileSize), "Game");
//Artificially cap FPS to keep memory and CPU usage low
gameWindow.setFramerateLimit(60);
//view1's size is defined externally, same size as the gameWindow, though
view1.setCenter(screenSizeX / 2, screenSizeY / 2 + mapTileSize);

//Load GUI Elements
//I've found that trying to load these inside the setGUIElements function leads to the 
//texture memory to be deleted, so I'm left with white spaces
sf::Texture guiElements;
if (!guiElements.loadFromFile("Resources/guiElements.png"))
{
    std::cout << "Error loading guiElements.png\n";
}

sf::Font arial;
if (!arial.loadFromFile("Resources/arial.ttf"))
{
    std::cout << "Error loading arial.tff\n";
}
setGUIElements();
activeTileSprite.setTexture(tileTexture);
upArrowX.setTexture(guiElements);
downArrowX.setTexture(guiElements);
upArrowY.setTexture(guiElements);
downArrowY.setTexture(guiElements);
saveButton.setTexture(guiElements);
editBoxX.setFont(arial);
editBoxY.setFont(arial);

//Selector Rectangle
sf::RectangleShape Selected(sf::Vector2f(mapTileSize, mapTileSize));
Selected.setFillColor(sf::Color(0,0,0,0));
Selected.setOutlineThickness(2);
Selected.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(255,0,0));
Selected.setPosition(-1000,-1000);

//Set up toolbox string values
tempXTileValue = std::to_string((_ULonglong)xTileValue);
tempYTileValue = std::to_string((_ULonglong)yTileValue);

while (gameWindow.isOpen())
{   
    /************************************/
    //Mouse Input Defined Here
    /***********************************/
    //Get mouse position relative to the window
    sf::Vector2f mousePositionGlobal = gameWindow.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(gameWindow));
    sf::Vector2i mousePositionLocal = sf::Mouse::getPosition(gameWindow);

    sf::Event event;
    while (gameWindow.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        {
            gameWindow.close();
        }
        if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased)
        {
            if (event.key.code == sf::Mouse::Left)
            {
                std::cout << "Global Mouse Position:\n" << "X: " << mousePositionGlobal.x << " Y: " << mousePositionGlobal.y << "\n\n";
                std::cout << "Local Mouse Position:\n" << "X: " << mousePositionLocal.x << " Y: " << mousePositionLocal.y << "\n\n";

                int mouseX = mousePositionGlobal.x;
                int mouseY = mousePositionGlobal.y;

                //Move the selector rectangle to where the mouse clicked
                if ((mouseX >= 0) && (mouseY >= 0))
                {
                    if (mousePositionLocal.x > 900 && mousePositionLocal.x < 1100 && mousePositionLocal.y > 30 && mousePositionLocal.y < 286)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Selected.setPosition((mouseX/32)*32, (mouseY/32)*32);

                        /*****************************************/
                        //These lines define what tile to be placed
                        //NOTE: map[][]'s first [] is the Y axis, and the second [] is the X axis!!
                        /*****************************************/
                        map[mouseY/32*32/32][mouseX/32*32/32].x = yTileValue;
                        map[mouseY/32*32/32][mouseX/32*32/32].y = xTileValue;
                    }
                }

                /********************/
                //Toolbox stuff
                /********************/
                //This can probably be written better ...
                //Up Arrow X
                if ((mousePositionLocal.x > screenSizeX * 0.95) && (mousePositionLocal.x < screenSizeX * 0.95 + 32) && (mousePositionLocal.y > screenSizeY * 0.096) && (mousePositionLocal.y < screenSizeY * 0.096 + 32))
                {
                    if (xTileValue < 10)
                    {
                        xTileValue ++;
                        std::cout << xTileValue << std::endl;
                        tempXTileValue = std::to_string((_ULonglong)xTileValue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xTileValue = 0;
                        std::cout << xTileValue << std::endl;
                        tempXTileValue = std::to_string((_ULonglong)xTileValue);
                    }
                }

                //Down Arrow X
                if ((mousePositionLocal.x > screenSizeX * 0.95) && (mousePositionLocal.x < screenSizeX * 0.95 + 32) && mousePositionLocal.y > 98 && mousePositionLocal.y < 130)
                {                   
                    if (xTileValue > 0)
                    {
                        xTileValue --;
                        std::cout << xTileValue << std::endl;
                        tempXTileValue = std::to_string((_ULonglong)xTileValue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xTileValue = 10;
                        std::cout << xTileValue << std::endl;
                        tempXTileValue = std::to_string((_ULonglong)xTileValue);
                    }
                }

                //Up Arrow Y
                if ((mousePositionLocal.x > screenSizeX * 0.95) && (mousePositionLocal.x < screenSizeX * 0.95 + 32) && mousePositionLocal.y > 148 && mousePositionLocal.y < 180)
                {
                    if (yTileValue < 10)
                    {
                        yTileValue ++;
                        std::cout << yTileValue << std::endl;
                        tempYTileValue = std::to_string((_ULonglong)yTileValue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        yTileValue = 0;
                        std::cout << yTileValue << std::endl;
                        tempYTileValue = std::to_string((_ULonglong)yTileValue);
                    }
                }

                //Down Arrow Y
                if ((mousePositionLocal.x > screenSizeX * 0.95) && (mousePositionLocal.x < screenSizeX * 0.95 + 32) && mousePositionLocal.y > 188 && mousePositionLocal.y < 220)
                {
                    if (yTileValue > 0)
                    {
                        yTileValue --;
                        std::cout << yTileValue << std::endl;
                        tempYTileValue = std::to_string((_ULonglong)yTileValue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        yTileValue = 10;
                        std::cout << yTileValue << std::endl;
                        tempYTileValue = std::to_string((_ULonglong)yTileValue);
                    }
                }

                //Save Button
                if (mousePositionLocal.x > screenSizeX * 0.886 && mousePositionLocal.x < screenSizeX * 0.886 + 32 && mousePositionLocal.y > screenSizeY * 0.414 - 32 && mousePositionLocal.y < screenSizeY * 0.414)
                {
                    saveMap();
                }
            }

            if (event.key.code == sf::Mouse::Right)
            {
                Selected.setPosition(-1000, - 1000);
            }
        }
        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased)
        {
            if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::X)
            {
                showToolBox = !showToolBox;
            }
        }

        //View Managing
        viewCenter = view1.getCenter();
        viewSize = view1.getSize();

        /*************************/
        //Scrolling
        /************************/
        if ((mousePositionLocal.x > screenSizeX * 0.83) && (mousePositionLocal.x < screenSizeX) && (mousePositionLocal.y > mapTileSize) && (mousePositionLocal.y < screenSizeY * 0.43) && (showToolBox == true))
        {
            enableScroll = false;
        }
        else
        {
            enableScroll = true;
        }
        if ((mousePositionLocal.y < screenSizeY * 0.1) && (enableScroll == true))
        {
            //If the view would leave the map by scrolling; don't scroll
            if (viewCenter.y < mapTileSize * 10.7)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                scroll(0,-scrollSpeed);
            }
        }
        if ((mousePositionLocal.y > screenSizeY * 0.9) && (enableScroll == true))
        {
            if (viewCenter.y > ((mapSizeY * mapTileSize)) - (mapTileSize * 9))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                scroll(0,scrollSpeed);
            }
        }
        if (mousePositionLocal.x < screenSizeX * 0.1 && enableScroll == true)
        {
            if (viewCenter.x < (mapTileSize * 17))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                scroll(-scrollSpeed,0);
            }
        }
        if ((mousePositionLocal.x > screenSizeX * 0.9) && enableScroll == true)
        {
            if (viewCenter.x > (mapSizeX * mapTileSize) - (mapTileSize * 17))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                scroll(scrollSpeed,0);
            }
        }

        //Clear buffer
        gameWindow.clear();

        //The view has to be set in the draw function
        //for a reason that is not yet clear to me.
        gameWindow.setView(view1);

        //Add stuff to new buffer
        //Y loop
        for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++)
        {
            //X loop
            for (int j = 0; j < map[i].size(); j++)
            {
                if ((map[i][j].x != -1) && (map[i][j].y != -1))
                {
                    tiles.setPosition(j * mapTileSize, i * mapTileSize);
                    tiles.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(map[i][j].x * mapTileSize, map[i][j].y * mapTileSize, mapTileSize, mapTileSize));
                    gameWindow.draw(tiles);
                }
            }
        }

        //Draw the Selector rectangle
        gameWindow.draw(Selected);

        if (showToolBox == true)
        {
            activeTileSprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(mapTileSize*yTileValue, mapTileSize*xTileValue, mapTileSize, mapTileSize));

            //Draw toolbox
            gameWindow.draw(toolbarBox);
            gameWindow.draw(activeTileSprite);

            gameWindow.draw(upArrowX);
            gameWindow.draw(downArrowX);

            gameWindow.draw(upArrowY);
            gameWindow.draw(downArrowY);

            //Update the strings for X and Y here
            //Otherwise, it doesn't work for some reason
            editBoxX.setString("Y: " + tempXTileValue);
            editBoxY.setString("X: " + tempYTileValue);

            gameWindow.draw(editBoxX);
            gameWindow.draw(editBoxY);

            gameWindow.draw(saveButton);
        }
        //Render buffer
        gameWindow.display();
    }
}
openfile.close();
return;
}
```

Please let me know if I need to add (or remove) any information. 

I've checked around and couldn't find any similar questions, so hopefully I didn't overlook anything, and properly explained my issue.

Thanks again,

helpMeLearnC++

P.S. I should mention that I'm not a complete beginner, but I'm not super advanced, either.

P.S.S. After trying what Selbie suggested, I noticed that, rather paradoxically, my game wasn't updating unless the mouse was moving ... now I wonder why that would cause BETTER performance than when it wasn't moving ... (or the code I used didn't work properly).

P.S.S.S. After messing with the code some more, I found what I think was expected: while the mouse is moving, the gameWindow.pollEvent() takes precedence over the while(gameWindow.isOpen()) loop, which does the drawing and was likely what was killing my performance. Now the question becomes what the best method of dealing with this is.

P.S.S.S.S. For those curious, and assuming my method for checking FPS was right, I was rendering about 27,000 frames per second (my test was very small, so though I think it seems a bit high, I wouldn't completely discredit it).

**By moving the mousePositionGlobal and mousePositionLocal into the pollEvent loop, I was able to knock down performance from about 20-35% to about 8-15%, with it going down the rest of the way (to about 3%) when the mouse was moving. So, progress was made, but I'm still not sure what causes the discrepancy... Since the FPS has gone up to about 35,000 I'm going to assume that my code for calculating it is wrong. Any other suggestions?**

Comment: No idea what sfml is, but you are looping `while(gameWindow.isOpen())` and not blocking in `while(gameWindow.pollEvent(event))`, so I don't see how it wouldn't rail a CPU.  As there is nothing that stops the CPU, the CPU will just continue going.  Amusingly, if no events occur, no redraw occurs either, which means event-less animation (or what have you) doesn't work.... swapping `pollEvent` for `waitEvent` might fix your problem, but even that isn't right unless you force "self events" to handle non-user-sourced updates (like animations).

Comment: SFML stands for "Simple and Fast Multimedia Library" - it's just an open-source library. Funnily enough, that's the recommended syntax on the documentation, and it's what I'm using in the other file (the one that doesn't have huge performance issues). For the sake of this editor, waitEvent will probably help, but I'm hoping to use this as the core for some other projects, so I'd like to see if a better solution arises. Thanks though!

Comment: Are you printing stuff whenever the mouse moves? That will do it.

Comment: I'm updating two variables (a position X and a position Y), but I'm not printing anything. I do have checks for when the mouse is inside certain bounds, but while testing for performance, being inside or outside does not seem to have an impact. Besides, the problem isn't when the performance is low (I can manage problems like these myself :D), but when it's high.

Comment: Your CPU is certainly going to be pinned in a loop like this, considering there are no blocking operations. You could throw in a sleep, but your application won't respond to events while its sleeping. My advice would be to use `window.waitEvent()` to block for events, and have a custom render event that is raised every 1/60 of a second to do the rendering. I'm not familiar with the implementation of waitEvent however; if it's implemented as a tight polling loop, it won't help you here anyway. Otherwise you'll have to look into threading, if you're worried about CPU usage (I wouldn't be).

Comment: Thanks for the great idea of the waitEvent()! It worked for solving the performance issues I was getting, but now the smooth scrolling I had in the previous project has gone away - it will only scroll while the mouse is moving. I'm now trying to figure that out, and at the moment, I'm testing to see if using both a waitEvent() and a pollEvent() will destroy anything...
I may try to make my own event that will occur every 1/60 seconds, and get my fixed timestep that way.... Hmm ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple game loop where you don't want to rail the CPU might look something like:

```
time last_render = now();
while( app_is_running ) {
  Event e;
  // eat all events.  Ideally, more important than rendering,
  // and should take only a little bit of time:
  while ( get_event(&e) ) {
    process_event(e); // <- note, does not render, should be **cheap**
  }
  // frame limit code:
  while (now()-last_render < frame_limit) {
    Event e;
    if (wait_for_event(&e, (frame_limit-delta)/2))
      process_event(e);
  }
  last_render = now(); // stamp before rendering
  render(); // also includes other game state updates.
}
```

now, sfml seems to lack `wait_for_event(Event*, timeout)` functionality.  Which means you cannot "go to sleep while still responding to events".  So sleeping either makes your event processing non responsive, or you have to rail it, or you need more than one thread.

We could whip up a thread safe queue, create a thread whose job is to `waitForEvent` and have it populate a queue we can wait for, and sleep on the queue and a timeout (basically work around what appears to be a sfml deficiency).

Or we can poll and rail a CPU.  Stay off my phone!

Or we can live with a 1 frame user input response delay (which I'd find unacceptable).

I am not a game developer, so take this advice with a mountain of salt.

Comment: This is interesting ... I was looking for something like the "wait_for_event" and couldn't find anything. 
I'm just doing this for fun, so if SFML seems lacking, I can always switch to something else. I'll look into this method too, just working on getting FPS to display now.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions, everybody! If I could, I'd give you all internet points, but it won't let me upvote you guys.

Comment: Thanks for all the great suggestions!
If I could give everyone points I would, but it won't let me upvote anyone, so, sorry about that.
I've got it more or less to where I'm happy with it, so, thanks again!

Comment: @user4678593 if you just want to limit frame rate, SFML  has got setFrameLimit() method somewhere.

Comment: I mentioned I knew about that somewhere around here (at least, I'm fairly sure I did). The issue was simply checking for events in the pollEvent loop, when only the Window::Close should be there, and all other event checks should be done under Window.isOpen().

Thanks though! :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm willing to bet that your CPU is a quad-core. And that CPU percentage you are seeing is from the Windows Task Manager (or from some other app using the Windows perf counter).  I suspect this because you got a single threaded game loop that runs non-stop with no sleeping between frames.  Hence, your "20-35%" CPU is really your program taking up a full core on your chip.  That's typical of any game loop that wants to render at the highest frame rate possible.

I suspect that on your graphics card, "moving the mouse" generates similar performance characteristics with other windowed games as well.  When you move the mouse, Windows graphics gets a higher priority than the game window and stalls the rendering of your game loop.  Hence, when the mouse is moving around, your code is still running, but at a much lower frame rate.  Either of the .draw() or .display() calls are getting blocked as a result of the graphics system having to handle a drawing request outside of the game window.  Hence, your game loop blocks and uses less CPU.

My advice would be to add a frame rate counter to your game window.  Something that shows the number of frames accumulated in the last second (requires a few extra integer variables, time functions, and some division to compute frame rate).  I'm guessing you'll see the frame rate counter slow down when the mouse is moving.

Also, do an internet search for "code profiling tool". Some versions of Visual Studio have on built in. They should where your code is spending the majority of its time.

Comment: You're right about the quad core, and I thought about that myself. What baffles me, however, is that the setFramerateLimit has no impact ... I've tried different values, and the exact same thing happens. Would setting a fixed timestep fix the issue? Since the timestep would only really impact the processing speed, not the draw speed ...

Comment: Have you measured your frame rate (see the suggestion I made about rendering a frame rate counter)?  You could always insert Sleep statements on each loop to have the frame rate limited. Or do what Yakk suggests in his answer.

Comment: I did! Thanks for the suggestion, it was great. It helped me figure out (which others hinted) that the mouse moving was overriding some things. Thanks to the suggestion from Yakk, and AtlasC1, I tried using gameWindow.waitEvent() instead of gameWindow.pollEvent(), and that pretty much fixed it - CPU usage has been staying under 3%. However, (and this might be outside the scope of this question) I've lost my smooth scrolling from the other project - it now only scrolls when the mouse is moving. So I'm still trying to figure that out.